# Как получить MAC адрес сетевого адаптера, который используется по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, сеть

Как получить `MAC` адрес сетевого адаптера, который используется по умолчанию, т.е. через который идет трафик в\из интернета при использовании сокета?

**Update:** 
Нашел код для вывода всех сетевых адаптеров через `NetBios`, пример:

```
bool GetAdapterInfo(int nAdapterNum, std::string & sMAC)
    {
        // Reset the LAN adapter so that we can begin querying it 
        NCB Ncb;
        memset(&Ncb, 0, sizeof(Ncb));
        Ncb.ncb_command = NCBRESET;
        Ncb.ncb_lana_num = nAdapterNum;
        if (Netbios(&Ncb) != NRC_GOODRET) 
            return false;

        // Prepare to get the adapter status block 
        memset(&Ncb, 0, sizeof(Ncb));
        Ncb.ncb_command = NCBASTAT;
        Ncb.ncb_lana_num = nAdapterNum;
        strcpy((char *)Ncb.ncb_callname, "*");
        struct ASTAT 
        {
            ADAPTER_STATUS adapt;
            NAME_BUFFER NameBuff[30];
        } Adapter;
        memset(&Adapter, 0, sizeof(Adapter));
        Ncb.ncb_buffer = (unsigned char *)&Adapter;
        Ncb.ncb_length = sizeof(Adapter);

        // Get the adapter's info and, if this works, return it in standard,
        // colon-delimited form.
        if (Netbios(&Ncb) == 0) {
            char acMAC[18];
            sprintf(acMAC, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[0]),
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[1]),
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[2]),
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[3]),
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[4]),
                int(Adapter.adapt.adapter_address[5]));
            sMAC = acMAC;
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> GetMac()
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> result;
        LANA_ENUM AdapterList;
        NCB Ncb;
        memset(&Ncb, 0, sizeof(NCB));
        Ncb.ncb_command = NCBENUM;
        Ncb.ncb_buffer = (unsigned char *)&AdapterList;
        Ncb.ncb_length = sizeof(AdapterList);
        Netbios(&Ncb);
        std::string sMAC;
        for (int i = 0; i < AdapterList.length; ++i) 
        {
            if (GetAdapterInfo(AdapterList.lana[i], sMAC)) 
                result.push_back(std::wstring(sMAC.begin(), sMAC.end()));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

---

Но остается открытым вопрос - как получить `MAC` адрес адаптера по умолчанию?

Comment: Причем тут `c++11`?

Comment: @alexolut, доступны средства `C++11` стандарта.

Comment: В `c++` всё равно нет ничего для работы с сетью. Хоть 11, хоть какой другой. Это либо `boost\asio`, либо `winsock`.

Comment: @alexolut, исправил на `C++`.

Comment: Пытаетесь сочинить авторизацию и привязку по MAC? Идея изначально порочна. Строго говоря (и рассматривая общий случай), такого адаптера нет. Потому как решение, о том, через какой адаптер что пойдет, принимается на основе таблицы маршрутизации, которая может быть достаточно запутанной. А еще, на машине может быть настроено агрегирование интерфейсов, тогда пакеты идут через разные адаптеры (в зависимости от алгоритма балансировки, которых десяток и которые комбинируются). Итого, нормального решения на все случаи жизни вы не приведете. Остаются костыли.

Comment: Как правило, активный интерфейс на пользовательской машине один, его и берите. Если интерфейсов куча, надо смотреть таблицу маршрутизации - искать в ней, на какой адаптер повешен маршрут по умолчанию. Если есть что-то более сложное, например, маршрут по умолчанию назначен на виртуальный адаптер - вам не повезло. Порочна сама идея использовать MAC под авторизацию, не для этого он предназначен.

Comment: @All - добавил метки `C` и `C++` - чтобы обозначить язык, на котором нужен пример реализации. Без меток - пример могут написать на шарпе, питоне, яве, дельфи и т.д. А нужен пример конкретно под си или плюсы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз никто не захотел помочь, накатал свой велосипед и выкладываю тут в помощь другим, возможно код в чем то неверный, проверял только на своей системе:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

template<typename T>
static std::string HexToString(T uval)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(sizeof(uval) * 2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << +uval;
    std::string strToConvert = ss.str();
    std::transform(strToConvert.begin(), strToConvert.end(), strToConvert.begin(), ::toupper);
    return strToConvert;
}

std::wstring GetMac()
{
    std::wstring result;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;
    ULONG family = AF_INET;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;
    ULONG outBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES);
    pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)MALLOC(outBufLen);

    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) 
    {
        FREE(pAddresses);
        pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)MALLOC(outBufLen);
    }

    if (pAddresses == NULL) 
        return L"";

    dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);
    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) 
    {
        if (pAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0)
        {
            std::string str;
            for (i = 0; i < pAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength; i++)
            {
                if (i == (pAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength - 1))
                    str += HexToString((unsigned char)pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
                else
                    str += HexToString((unsigned char)pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]) + ":";
            }
            result = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
        }
    }
    FREE(pAddresses);
    return result;
}
```

p.s. от версии с `NetBios` отказался в связи с отсутствием его на `Windows Vista`, `Windows Server 2008` по умолчанию.

Comment: Тому, кто поставил минус - напишите свой ответ или укажите ошибки или минусы приведенного выше кода.